# How to override Angular2 tree component CSS

Tags: css, angular

I am working on an angular2 project and in that I am using a third party component, Angular2-tree-component. In that component JS file, they are using color coding of highlighting a particular node with X color code.
I want to modify it with Y color code but unable to do so.
In orginal JS file below is the line of code:

> .tree-node-focused > .node-wrapper > .node-content-wrapper { background: #e7f4f9 }

I am trying to override this color coding to some other code for below html code:

> ```
>   <p-panel header="Schema">
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="col-sm-12">
>         <Tree #tree [nodes]="LHSNodes" [focused]="true" [options]="optionsForLHS" (onInitialized)="getLHSTree(tree.treeModel)">
>           <template #treeNodeTemplate let-node >
>             <span>
>               <input type="checkbox" name="node.data.selected" value="{{node.data.selected}}" (click)= "onCheckBoxClick($event, node, 'LHS')" [(ngModel)]="node.data.selected">
>            <label *ngIf="!node.data.isEdit">{{node.data.documentUri}}</label> 
>             <input *ngIf="node.data.isEdit" id="node.data.documentUri" value="{{node.data.documentUri}}" [(ngModel)]="node.data.documentUri" type="text" size="10" pInputText (keyup.enter)="updateName(node)" />
>            </span>
>           </template>
>         </Tree>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </p-panel>
> ```

I am not understanding what should I write in my css file because same line of code is not working with updated value.
Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Comment: can you share @Component decorator content? ( What kind of encapsulation are you using? )

Comment: Below is the one: 

@Component({
  selector: 'ub-interface-model-detail',
  templateUrl: './interface-model-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./interface-model-detail.component.css']
})

I am not able to understand how we basically code css so that on focus it will pick color code from my css file instaead of third party library css

Comment: I do have the same problem. Anyone?